# How to get max value and using group by clause

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
select transactions_id,
    time_stamp,
    clock
from times
group by transactions_id
having sum(distinct type) = 1
```

now, I would like to get `max` value depending on `id`.

I used below queries but not worked:

```
select max(id),
    transactions_id,
    time_stamp,
    clock
from times
group by transactions_id
having sum(distinct type) = 1
```

or

```
select transactions_id,
    time_stamp,
    clock
from times
group by transactions_id
having sum(distinct type) = 1
    and max(id)
```

for example:

I have three conditions:

1. `type` must be 1
2. `group by` `transactions_id`
3. `max` `id`

[image]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.  Also, can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find aggregates in one query and join its result with the table to get the relevant rows.

```
select *
from times t1
join (
    select transactions_id,
        max(id) as id
    from times
    where type = 1
    group by transactions_id
    ) t2 using (transactions_id, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by transactions_id order by id desc) as seqnum
      from times t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I am not sure what `having sum(distinct type) = 1`.  That condition is not explained in the question.

Comment: My DBMS is `mysql`.